# Angular Js - Border becomes red when pasting a url - why?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, border

Hi I am confused I dont know why is this happening I am testing this on mac and on chromes (windows). I have a field named `website` in which I am testing that is a url valid or not. It works most of the time fine but if there is an error it will cause the border red and show the error in tooltip but There comes a strange issue sometimes when i paste a url copied from somewhere and it is valid i know for sure because the error does not show in tooltip and the form does submitted even though but the border becomes red ? Why

**Input**

```
<input type="text" 
       class="add_role_input width-100-perc  border-4px-rad" 
       id="website"
       name="website"
       ng-model="seAddArtist.customCandWebsite"
       placeholder="Enter website of candidate"
       autocomplete="off"
       uib-tooltip="{{seAddArtist.invalidWebNewUserMsg}}"
       ng-class="{'error_border': seAddArtist.NewUserWebTooltip}"
       tooltip-placement="top-right"
       tooltip-is-open="seAddArtist.NewUserWebTooltip"
       tooltip-enable="seAddArtist.enableWebNewUserTooltip"
       ng-blur="seAddArtist.validateForNewUser(3)">
```

This is basically a filter which I am using in controller.

**Filter**

```
filters.filter('urlValidate', function($filter) {
  return function(url) {
    var reg = /\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i;
    if (url === '' || !reg.test(url)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  };
});
```

Now how can i find this bug ? I have tried hundred of times and it happens once in a blue moon but it does happen.

Comment: I think this is not a bug. I guess `ng-class="{'error_border': seAddArtist.NewUserWebTooltip}"` error-border css class is who set red to the border. So, somebody is set `true` NewUserWebTooltip

Comment: what do this `validateForNewUser` method??

Comment: i double check it it does not becomes true, because if it gets true the tooltip will be shown too.